# Unusual warning when deallocating memory of a 2D array in C

Tags: c, memory, free, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to free the memory I allocated for my 2D array.

The code is working fine, but I always have warnings when compiling.

I tried 2 different methods but each time, a new warning appears.

```
    int* array = fillArray(); //malloc (n*m*sizeof*array)

    ...
    DeallocateMemory(array, n*m); //Where n and m are length and height

    void DeallocateMemory(int* array, int length)
    {
          for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
              //free(array[i]);
              //free((void*)array[i]);
          }
    }
    free(array);
```

Ok so at first, I wrote `free(array[i])` but the warning said :

*passing argument 1 of `free` makes pointer from integer without a cast
note: expected `void*` but argument is of type `int*`

So I wrote `void*`, but now the warning is :

*cast to a pointer from integer of different size*

What should I do to get rid of both errors? Thanks!

Comment: How are you allocating the array? You should have one corresponding `free()` per `malloc()`.

Comment: malloc(n * m * sizeof *array);
Thanks I just edited

Comment: Should `int* array` be `int** array`? Or else it doesn't make sense why you're `free`ing every element within it.

Comment: There is something I don't understand then. When am I suppose to free every element of an array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just say `free(array);` Need not to free every location of array. At every location of array, an `int` is stored freeing that `int` causing the warning.

if you have 2D array then only it make sense the way you did.

```
 //Allocate the memory
 int** array = malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
 for (unsigned int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
     array[k] = malloc(m * sizeof(int));
 }

 //Deallocate the memory
void DeallocateMemory(int** array, int n) {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
           free(array[i]);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `array` is a pointer to `int`, then `array[i]` is an `int`; trying to `free(array[i])` is the same as trying to free an integer - it makes no sense, and that's what the compiler complains about.

Assuming this is a flat array holding integers, all you have to do to free it is:

```
free(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use pointer of pointer array you can `free` memory like in your question. I mean if you allocate memory and build two dimensional array like that.

```
int **array = malloc(m * sizeof(int *));
for (i = 0; i < m; i++) { 
  array[i]=malloc(n * sizeof(int));
}
```

and then you can free all allocated memory like that.

```
for (i = 0; i < m; i++) { 
  free(array[i]);
}
free(array);
```

Finally, you used one dimensional array and you can free allocated memory like others answers.